# switch between pages in the flutter using the Smooth Page Indicator

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a steamer to the next page using the Smooth Page Indicator widget. I added this widget to the page but I don't know how to add the pages I want to go to. I will be grateful for your help
My code :

```html
final controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8, keepPage: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:
      Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 35.0),
             
             Container(
               child: SmoothPageIndicator(
                 controller: controller,
                 count: 2,
                 effect: JumpingDotEffect(
                   dotHeight: 16,
                   dotWidth: 16,
                   jumpScale: .7,
                   verticalOffset: 15,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            
          ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _scanQR();
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.qr_code),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
    );
  }
```

the name of my page to which I want to go Page2, and this Page1

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the `PageView` widget : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

By passing the same `PageController` to both, the `PageView` and the `SmoothPageIndicator` widgets you should be able to swipe left and right AND see the dots move along. That simple.